# Cant get foreign key values when submitting form

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Im currently working in my `ASP.NET Core` project. I have created a few classes witch i have mapped to Database tables.

Errand class:

```
public class Errand : IDbEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PANumber { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Issuer { get; set; }
    public string Stakeholders { get; set; }
    public string Background { get; set; }
    public string DescriptionOfMission { get; set; }
    public string AcceptanceCriteria { get; set; }
    public string TestObject { get; set; }
    public DateTime AvailableFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime TestStart { get; set; }
    public DateTime TestDelivery { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public DateTime Updated { get; set; }

    public int CoreId { get; set; }
    public virtual Core Core { get; set; }

    public int MachineTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual MachineType MachineType { get; set; }

    public int ProjectNrId { get; set; }
    public virtual ProjectNumber ProjectNr { get; set; }

    public int TestTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual Group TestType { get; set; }

    public virtual DBErrandStatus status { get; set; }
}
```

And the other classes looks the same as eachother.
Here is the class of Core:

```
public class Core : IDbEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public DateTime Updated { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Errand> Errands { get; set; }
}
```

I have made a migration to the database and everything works just fine, and the Errand table contains foreign keys of `Core, Group, MachineType & ProjectNumber`.

Now to my problem. I am trying to create A `Errand` and in the view where the user will choose values for the errand i have made dropdowns for the foreign keys. here is the code for this:

```
 <form method="post" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="ExecuteCreateErrand">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <label>PA number:</label>
            <input asp-for="@Model.errand.PANumber" class="form-input" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label>Title:</label>
            <input asp-for="@Model.errand.Description" class="form-input" placeholder="Title" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <label>Core:</label>
            <select asp-for="@Model.errand.Core" class="form-input">
                @foreach(var core in Model.Core)
                {
                    <option>@core.Name</option>
                }
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label>Project Nr:</label>
            <select asp-for="@Model.errand.ProjectNr" class="form-input">
                @foreach(var projNr in Model.ProjectNumber)
                {
                    <option>@projNr.Name</option>
                }
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <label>Machine type:</label>
            <select asp-for="@Model.errand.MachineType" class="form-input">
                @foreach (var MT in Model.MachineType)
                {
                    <option>@MT.Name</option>
                }
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label>Issuer:</label>
            <input asp-for="@Model.errand.Issuer" class="form-input" value="@Model.User.Username" type="text" readonly />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <label>Test type</label>
            <select asp-for="@Model.errand.TestType" class="form-input">
                @foreach (var TestType in Model.TestType)
                {
                    <option>@TestType.Name</option>
                }
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label>Stakeholders</label>
            <input class="form-input" asp-for="@Model.errand.Stakeholders" placeholder="Stakeholders" type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="sandbox-container" class=" span5 col-md-4">
            <label>Testobject avalible from:</label>
            <input asp-for="@Model.errand.AvailableFrom" class="form-input" type="text" value="@DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")" />
        </div>

        <div id="sandbox-container" class=" span5 col-md-4">
            <label>Desired start of test:</label>
            <input asp-for="@Model.errand.TestStart" class="form-input" type="text" value="@DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")" />
        </div>

        <div id="sandbox-container" class=" span5 col-md-4">
            <label>Desired end of test:</label>
            <input asp-for="@Model.errand.TestDelivery" class="form-input" type="text" value="@DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10"></div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-block mt-4 vBtn">Create Errand</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

But when i later set a breakpoint on the action that runs once the form is submitted I get that `Errand.Core = null` and `Errand.CoreId = 0`

Here is the code for the action:

```
public IActionResult ExecuteCreateErrand([FromForm] Errand errand)
    {
        var SQL = new SQLErrandStorage();
        var handler = new ErrandHandler(SQL);
        handler.Create(errand);

        return RedirectToAction("RenderAllErrandsView", "Home");
    }
```

The `[FromForm] Errand errand` returns this

> Core = null and CoreId = 0

The Action calls this method:

```
public void Create(Errand errand)
{
     errandStorage.CreateErrand(errand);
}
```

which in turn calls this method that creates the errand:

```
public void CreateErrand(Errand errand)
    {
        using (var db = new PADBContext())
        {
            db.Errand.Add(errand);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

My question is how I can make the foreign keys to be attached in the submitted form. How can i change the values `Core = null and CoreId = 0` to the one i choose in the dropdown?

I hope that explains my problem good enough. I would really appreciate some help or some feedback. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be the error binding of `asp-for` value in `select` tag helper .The `Select Tag Helper` `asp-for` specifies the model property name for the select element ,not a model.

If you want to get `Errand.CoreId`, you could set the `asp-for` of select tag helper like below :

```
<label>Core:</label>
<select asp-for="@Model.errand.CoreId" class="form-input">
      @foreach (var core in Model.Core)
       {
         <option value="@core.Id">@core.Name</option>
       }
 </select>
```

If you want to get `Errand.Core`, you could set the asp-for of select tag helper like below :

```
<label>Core:</label>
<select asp-for="@Model.errand.Core.Id" class="form-input">
      @foreach (var core in Model.Core)
       {
         <option value="@core.Id">@core.Name</option>
       }
 </select>
```

Comment: I actually solved it, but i tried out your solution to and it worked as well. The only thing is that for your solution is that i have to choose if i want the `coreId` or the `Core` to be populated when the form submits, but it was an easy fix, I populated the `core` and told the `coreId` it should use the `Core.Id` as it's value. Really smooth solution, thanks alot!!